# Linking ilutOgl functions

Tags: c++, opengl, devil

Is there something else besides ilut.h I have to #include to get ilutOgl functions to work? Because ilutRenderer(ILUT_OPENGL) is recognized, but ilutOglLoadImage("myimage.jpeg") "was not declared in this scope".

http://openil.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow DevIL tutorial I hate you. My header has ilutGLLoadImage NOT ilutOglLoadImage! AND the part of the header that allowed this chunk of methods to be available was commented out! Someone owes me a couple hours of my life back.